# Different Rows To Combine

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table:

```
    Company   Year  CustomerCount1  CustomerCount2
    1         2010  100             150
    1         2011  120             130
    1         2012  300             140
    2         2010  50              90
    2         2011  45              110
    2         2012  60              120
```

CustomerCount1 is the number of customers in the begining of the year
CustomerCount2 is the number of customers in the middle of the year
How woud you run a query to get such an output

```
    Company   Year2010        Year2012
    1         100             140
    2         50              120
```

where
100 is the CustomerCount1 in 2010 for company1
140 is the CustomerCount2 in 2012 for company1
50 is the CustomerCount1 in 2010 for company2
120 is the CustomerCount2 in 2012 for company2

Answer (score 1):

Seems that your data structures could use some normalization. But you can easily use conditional aggregation for something like this.

```
declare @Something table
(
    Company int
    , Year int
    , CustomerCount1 int
    , CustomerCount2 int
)

insert @Something
values
(1, 2010, 100, 150)
, (1, 2011, 120, 130)
, (1, 2012, 300, 140)
, (2, 2010, 50, 90)
, (2, 2011, 45, 110)
, (2, 2012, 60, 120)

select Company
    , max(case when Year = 2010 then CustomerCount1 end) as Year2010
    , max(case when Year = 2012 then CustomerCount2 end) as Year2012
from @Something
where Year in (2010, 2012)
group by Company
```